# Shorten javascript RegExp Conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, loops, if-statement

I have the following javascript function that runs on keyup inside of an input:

```
var passwordInput = document.getElementsByName("newPassword")[0].value;

var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('[a-z]');
var numbers = new RegExp('[0-9]');

if ( passwordInput.match(lowerCase) ) {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="1"]').addClass('check-rule--pass');
} else {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="1"]').removeClass('check-rule--pass');
}

if (passwordInput.match(upperCase)) {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="2"]').addClass('check-rule--pass');
} else {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="2"]').removeClass('check-rule--pass');
}

if(passwordInput.match(numbers)) {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="3"]').addClass('check-rule--pass');
} else {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="3"]').removeClass('check-rule--pass');
}

if(passwordInput.length >= 8) {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="4"]').addClass('check-rule--pass');
} else {
    $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="4"]').removeClass('check-rule--pass');
}
```

The addClasses inside of each conditional simply add a class to an li to show that that condition has been met. I am wondering if anyone has any tips on how I could shorten this or make it more concise, specifically the first three conditions that are very similar.

Comment: Ah, the validation world, the joy! In your shoes I would use a third party lib, yeah it costs extra kb, but it will save you time. In your case, perhaps https://jqueryvalidation.org/ might be something you want to look at.

Comment: If it weren't dependent upon `[data-index="#"]`, you could condense it all into this `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8})`, but it looks like you are tracking individual strengths.

Comment: @sln Yep, that's correct...I have a progress bar that is updated based on each conditional.  Was just wondering if anyone had any tips on compacting this or making it more concise.

Comment: You could condense the code into a for loop and some arrays, but the context can't be changed because of individual tracking.

Comment: @sln Yea that's what I was thinking, seems like that would be cleaner.  Just not sure exactly how to do it.  Want to provide an example for a nice shiny checkmark :)

Comment: JS is readonly to me..

Comment: @Oli: personally, I make a difference between a developer (someone able to produce an algorithm) and an API user. For a so basic task, is there really a need to use a module/third party lib?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte agreed

Comment: @JordanBarber: About your problem, perhaps you can store your patterns in an array and then use a loop: the index of each item (once incremented) is the value of 'data-index'. In this way you write only one 'if...else' statement.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's definitely what I'm trying to do, I'm just having trouble doing it :)

Comment: Perhaps you should re-think your approach and look at what it is that you are trying to accomplish. You want a meter 1-4 depending on password strenght?

Comment: I think you should post that question in codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: @Oli: conclusion: API users aren't quick witted too.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yeah, you are not improving your case you know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this might help save some lines and characters :

```
var passwordInput = document.getElementsByName("newPassword")[0].value;

var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('[a-z]');
var numbers = new RegExp('[0-9]');

var x = [0,0,0,0];

x[0] = passwordInput.match(lowerCase) ? 1 : 0;
x[1] = passwordInput.match(upperCase) ? 1 : 0;
x[2] = passwordInput.match(numbers) ? 1 : 0;
x[3] = passwordInput.length > 7 ? 1 : 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (x[i] == 1) {
        $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="' + (i+1) + '"]').addClass('check-rule--pass');
    } else {
        $('.strength-check__rule[data-index="' + (i+1) + '"]').removeClass('check-rule--pass');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doubt it can be shortened much more than this:

```
var passwordInput = $('[name=newPassword]').val();
var tests = {
  1:/[a-z]/.test(passwordInput),
  2:/[A-Z]/.test(passwordInput),
  3:/[0-9]/.test(passwordInput),
  4:passwordInput.length >= 8
};
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++)
  $('.strength-check__rule[data-index=' +i+ ']')
  [ tests[i] ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]('check-rule--pass');
```

Comment: Nice idea using object, I think `for (var i in tests)` is more appropriate

Comment: Relationship-wise, property iteration seems more appropriate, but such would include inherited properties as well without `hasOwnProperty`. Assuming it isn't extended is just as bad of a practice as extending it in the first place, as it could break later if a script was included later which extended Object to get whatever functionality done which you required. [IE has its own issues with it](https://toddmotto.com/methods-to-determine-if-an-object-has-a-given-property/#gotchas-1). Call me "behind the times" if you wish, but after 17 years of JavaScript, I leave as much support as possible.

Comment: I got your point, but... What's the advantage using object instead array then?

Comment: Two advantages: one is because arrays start at index 0, and we're interested in indices 1 through 4. Sure, we could use `i+1` but then it harms readability. The second advantage is it makes the association of each of the keys with its test much more clear. If another test needs to be added at some point, the associations aren't lost since by giving each test a specific key, you're making it clear that the keys matter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your script I refactored it to something different. It can be factored even better but the idea is that you have a function that assess the password strength and from that value, you manipulate the strength meter.

```
<input type="text" name="newPassword" onkeyup="validate();">

<ul class="strength">
    <li class="strength-1">*</li>
    <li class="strength-2">*</li>
    <li class="strength-3">*</li>
    <li class="strength-4">*</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('ul.strength').css('list-style-type', 'none').find('li').css('float', 'left').hide();

    function getPasswordStrength(password) {
        var strength = 0;
        if(password.match(/[A-Z]/)) { strength++; }
        if(password.match(/[a-z]/)) { strength++; }
        if(password.match(/[0-9]/)) { strength++; }
        if(password.length > 8) { strength++; }
        return strength;
    }

    function validate() {
        var strength = getPasswordStrength(document.getElementsByName("newPassword")[0].value);

        $('ul.strength').find('li').hide();
        for(var  i = 1; i < strength + 1; i++) {
             $('li.strength-' + i).show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a `switch` `.attr()` to change the classes, something like:

```js
$("#pass").keyup(function(e) {
var pass = $("#pass").val();
switch (true) {
  case /((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.{8,})[^ ]*)/.test(pass):
    $("#stenght").attr("class", 'green');
    break;
  case /((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])[^ ]*)/.test(pass): 
    $("#stenght").attr("class",'blue');
    break;
  case /((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[^ ]*)/.test(pass):
    $("#stenght").attr("class", 'orange');
    break;
  case /((?=.*[a-z])[^ ]*)/.test(pass):
    $("#stenght").attr("class",'red');
    break;
}
  });
```

```css
.red{color:red;} .orange{color:orange;} .blue{color:blue;} .green{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pass" type="text"><br>
<span class="red" id="stenght">PASSWORD STENGHT<span>
```